# get selected rows in yii2 using gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can you give me a simple basic example on how to get the selected rows in yii2 gridview. I have tried all the examples existed on the forums but it's not working. I got this error: can't read property 'selectioncolumn' of undefined

Here is my code :

***the view :***

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchInstance,
        //'containerOptions' => ['class' => 'instance-pjax-container'],
        'id' => 'grid',

        'export' => false,
    'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'codebien',
            'designationbien',
            'codesousfamille',
            'numfacture',
            'dt',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],


]);?>


  <?= Html::SubmitButton( 'Affecter', [ 'class' => 'btn btn-success' , 'id' =>'x']) ?>    



  <?php
$script = <<< JS
$(function () {
         $('#x').click(function(){

            $.post(
   [ "listeaffecter", 
    {
        pk : $('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows')
    },]

);

         });

  });

JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

and here is my **controller** :

```
public function actionListeaffecter(){

                    $searchInstance = new InstanceSearch();
                    $dataProvider = $searchInstance->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
                    $pk = Yii::$app->request->post('pk'); 
                    if ($pk) {
                        print ($pk);
                    }

                         return $this->render('vueListeAaffecter', [
                            'searchInstance' => $searchInstance,
                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                            ]);

                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way

```
$('#your-grid-id').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

in your case

```
$('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```